# react-router-v6 : how to get axios returned data and use it in my component ArticleDetail return

Tags: react-router-dom

I'm using react-router-v6. I want to get daynamically the path and use it with axios. after I want to use the return data of axios in the return of my component ArticleDetail.

```
function ArticleDetail ()  {
    const articleID = useParams()
    axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/${articleID}`)
        .then( res => res.data) 
    
    return (
        <div>{res.data}</div>
    );
}

export default ArticleDetail;
```

Comment: Could you explain in detail, so that it will helpful to give a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the `articleID` route match param. Use the effect to issue the asynchronous GET request and store the result/response locally in state to be rendered.

```
function ArticleDetail ()  {
  const { articleID } = useParams();

  // State to cache fetched article data
  const [article, setArticle] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Make GET request
    axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/${articleID}`)
      .then(res => {
        // Update state
        setArticle(res.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // handle any rejected Promises or errors, etc...
      };
  }, [articleID]); // effect triggered when articleID updates
    
  // Return JSX to render state value
  return <div>{article}</div>;
}

export default ArticleDetail;
```